# Why do some charts have so few candlesticks?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets, chart

Why do some stock charts look like the one on this screenshot? Why does it have such low amount of candlesticks compared to for example TSLA?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the possibility of bad data, if no trading occurs in a given time period (an illiquid stock), there will be no candlestick.  This leads to intraday gaps in the candlestick chart.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when there is no actual trade taking place in those "-" periods. There could be a pair of bid and ask prices, but there were no incoming Market Order or Marketable Limit Order.